# AppleScript to find and delete a folder inside an FCPX library

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, script

I need to write or find a simple script to find, select and move to trash, folders within a Final Cut Pro X library. Because these libraries are bundles you can't search them in the normal way.

What I want is a script that runs every day, searches the libraries finds Folders (and their contents) called "Render Files" and then moves them to trash.

I can use automator to find the bundles, and to list the contents, but then I cannot get it to select only the 'Render Files' folders.

Comment: Any particular reason why you need AppleScript? I've added an answer that doesn't use AppleScript

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your crontab (`env EDITOR=nano crontab -e`):

```
@daily /usr/bin/find /path/to/fcplibraries -name "Render Files" -type d -delete
```

<sup>Keep backups and make sure you've got the right path.</sup>

Comment: Thanks George  I thought cron was deprecated in mac mavericks. I came up with this rm -R /Volumes/Home/RBPY/Final\ Cut\ Libraries/*.fcpbundle/*/Render\ Files which works but still not sure what to do to save it correctly and run it automatically at a set time.

Comment: @Doug Run `env EDITOR=nano crontab -e`, add a new line beginning with `@daily` then your command, then save.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a script to remove all Final Cut Render Files. Can be use to anyone, only need to point to final cut bundle.. that's it.

```
-- Check folder and delete Render Files folder
display alert "Choose Final Cut Pro X Project Bundle"
set theFolder to choose file
set renderfolder1 to "/*/Rende*" -- Folder Render Files
set renderfolder to POSIX path of theFolder -- Convert Path of Final Cut 
Project to shell script
try
    do shell script "rm -R " & renderfolder & renderfolder1
    display alert "Left overs from Final Cut Pro X successfully removed!" giving up after 3
on error errMsg
    display alert "There are not Final Cut Pro X Left overs to remove" giving up after 3
end try
```